# Features Eclipse rcp Resulting configuration does not contain the platform

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have several plugin package in 2 features. When I deploy thoses features ( in an update site ) I have the following error  "Resulting configuration does not contain the platform."

After googling I can find this http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/RCP_FAQ#My_own_RCP_plug-ins_are_contributed_by_a_feature._Why_is_the_update_manager_complaining_that_my_configuration_is_invalid.3F

But I dont see how to find my error(wich plugin is missing ), ANy Idea

Answer (score 0):

Does you feature.xml when open in the editor and "included features" tab selected contain "org.eclipse.rcp"? Sounds like you are not including the correct platform features in your feature.xml